# what is max(rowid) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below query is to delete duplicates rows in SALES_DETAILS, but what is max(rowid)?

```
delete SALES_DETAILS
  where rowid not in (select max(rowid)
                      from sales_details
                      group by txt_id,customer_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ROWID` is Oracle's pseudocolumn which holds address of a particular row. It lets database locate rows. You normally don't see it in table structure, but it's there and remains hidden. This doesn't mean though, that you can't use it :-)

Your DELETE statement removes every row from table *SALES_DETAILS* that is a duplicate based on `txt_id, customer_id` pair, just like you mentioned. So what this means is it removes duplicates but saves the row with highest rowid value within the group.

Please look it up in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) for more info.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't save the "last input row", but *a row* based on the highest rowid value (which is not necessarily the latest).

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure whether this may be an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that (typically) we have mainly "good" data and not many duplicates, then removing them can be achieved perhaps more efficiently by flipping this around to pick out the rowid's that *are* the duplicates, rather than *not* the duplicates, eg

```
delete from SALES_DETAILS
where rowid in (
  select rid
  from (
    select rowid rid, 
           row_number() over ( partition by txt_id,customer_id order by rowid ) as r
    from SALES_DETAILS
     )
    where r > 1
  )
```

There's a video explaining this here as well

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_m39BySTDU&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt&index=19