# Will rowid keep unchanged if I export from one oracle and then import to another oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table, and I export the data from my oracle server, and then  import the data into another oracle server.

My question is: for every row in the table, will the rowid keep unchanged after importing into another oracle?

I guess the answer is NO, but I have no idea how rowid is generated.

Comment: The documentation explains [how it is generated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html). The row IDs will almost certainly change on import to a new DB - the chances of *any* being exactly the same are extremely low. "If you delete and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example, then its rowid may change." And that's within the same DB; between DBs it's even more likely to change.

Comment: Why you asking? I hope you are not using ROWID for indicating relations?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. It is a perfect answer

Comment: @raymond-nijland some guy on the team wants to use rowid to identify each row, because the table has no primary key defined. I thought it was wrong,just ask to confirm.

Comment: @Tom - that guy is definitely wrong, yes *8-)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole, :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the row IDs will almost certainly change. Even within the same database, [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html):

> If you delete and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example, then its rowid may change.

The row ID represents the location of the row within a block, within a data file, within a tablespace. (That documentation explains that more.) Even if the target database has the same tablespaces and data files, the import will load data into files and blocks as efficiently as it can, and will not make any attempt to preserve old row IDs - which it won't know anyway as they are not part of the exported data. Even if it could try, that would involve writing each row to a specific place on disk, which would slow things down quite a bit, and existing data in the target DB might already be using the same row ID.

`ROWID` is a pseudocolumn, not part of the the actual row, and it would be meaningless to include it in the exported data.

> Although you can use the ROWID pseudocolumn in the SELECT and WHERE clause of a query, these pseudocolumn values are not actually stored in the database.

It isn't even necessarily unique.

Also, you shouldn't really be using it directly, except possibly within a single query/statement ([here is one use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50750329/266304)) or maybe procedure, as they can change even within an existing database if Oracle decides it needs to reorganize things. That's partly why the documentation also says:

> You should not use ROWID as the primary key of a table.

Comment: i didn't use Oracle database for some while now, i can't even remember a valid usercase where your would use the ROWID Pseudocolumn in a query..

Comment: You can use it to remove duplicates (delete where rowid != max rowid, say). OK, that isn't a query, I suppose *8-) More likely maybe - though not bulletproof - to store a rowid in a variable/collection in a procedure and reuse it later within that same call. I'm not sure I've ever actually needed to do that though...